# NodeJS: Помогите с Discord-ботом

Tags: node.js, discord

Хочу бота создать, да выходит такая ошибка:

```
node:events:994
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('emitter', 'EventEmitter', emitter);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "emitter" argument must be an instance of EventEmitter. Received type string ('ready')
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
    at eventTargetAgnosticAddListener (node:events:994:11)
    at Client.on (node:events:1081:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\My Works\Discord_Bot\bot.js:9:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v19.3.0
```

==============================================================================
Код вот такой:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Подключаем библиотеку discord.js
const {Client} = require('discord.js');
const comms = require("./comms.js"); // Подключаем файл с командами для бота
const fs = require('fs'); // Подключаем родной модуль файловой системы node.js  
let config = require('./config.json'); // Подключаем файл с параметрами и информацией
let token = config.token; // «Вытаскиваем» из него токен
let prefix = config.prefix; // «Вытаскиваем» из него префикс

Client.on('ready', function() {
  /* При успешном запуске, в консоли появится сообщение «[Имя бота] запустился!» */
  console.log(Client.user.username + " запустился!");
});


Client.on('message', (msg) => { // Реагирование на сообщения
  if (msg.author.username != Client.user.username && msg.author.discriminator != Client.user.discriminator) {
    var comm = msg.content.trim() + " ";
    var comm_name = comm.slice(0, comm.indexOf(" "));
    var messArr = comm.split(" ");
    for (comm_count in comms.comms) {
      var comm2 = prefix + comms.comms[comm_count].name;
      if (comm2 == comm_name) {
        comms.comms[comm_count].out(Client, msg, messArr);
      }
    }
  }
});


Client.login('token')
```

Подскажите, что делать или что исправить :(

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь вызвать методы класса `Client`, а не его объекта.

Так будет работать:

```
const client = new Client()

client.on('ready', function() {...})
client.on('message', (msg) => {...})

client.login('token')
```

Читайте документацию внимательнее и разберитесь с ООП.
[Документация](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/general/welcome)
[Пример](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html)